# Print between two patterns on a single line

Tags: awk, sed, scripting

I have a file with the following contents:

```
<alarm="yes">
<moduleId>aaa</moduleId>
<documentation>
<description>bbb</description>
<Object>ccc</Object>
</documentation>
</alarmSpecification>
<alarm="yes">
<moduleId>bbb</moduleId>
<documentation>
<description>abc</description>
<Object>xxx</Object>
</documentation>
</alarmSpecification>
```

I want to match the pattern and print in a single line.
Here, the pattern is alarm & alarmSpecification
Output will be like

```
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>aaa</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>bbb</description>,<Object>ccc</Object>,</documentation>,</alarmSpecification>
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>aaa</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>bbb</description>,<Object>ccc</Object>,</documentation>,</alarmSpecification>
```

Pls guide how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/<alarm/,/<\/alarmSpecification/{ORS = (/<\/alarmSpecification>/) ? "\n" : "," ;print}' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As this doesn't seem to be valid XML, it's probably better to use a general text processing too like `sed`:

```
sed 'H;/<alarm=/h;/<\/alarmSpecification>/!d;g;s/\n/,/g'
```

- `H` to append lines to the `H`old space
- `/<alarm=/h` to reset the collected lines on a new `<alarm` field
- `/<\/alarmSpecification>/!d` stop if this is not the alarmSpecification Line
- otherwise take the ilnes collected in hold space with `g` and replace the newlines with `,` with `s/\n/,/g`

Answer (score 0):

This really should be done using an XML parser. The solution below works for your example, but will fail on anything even slightly more complicated. It is rarely a good idea to use naive approaches like the one I am suggesting here to parse complex formats like XML. With that said, here's one ugly, fragile way that is only guaranteed to work on the specific, simple example you show:

```
$ perl -ne '$k=1 if /<alarm=/; $k=0 if /<\/alarmSpecification>/; s/\n/,/ if $k; print $k ? $_ : "\n"; ' file | sed 's/,$//'
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>aaa</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>bbb</description>,<Object>ccc</Object>,</documentation>
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>bbb</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>abc</description>,<Object>xxx</Object>,</documentation>
```

Comment: But then you need to teach the XML parser how to parse this invalid format (`</alarmSpecification>` seems to close `<alarm>`)

Comment: yeah... true. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='</alarmSpecification>\n' -v ORS= -F'\n' -v OFS=',' '{$NF=$NF RT} 1' file
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>aaa</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>bbb</description>,<Object>ccc</Object>,</documentation>,</alarmSpecification>
<alarm="yes">,<moduleId>bbb</moduleId>,<documentation>,<description>abc</description>,<Object>xxx</Object>,</documentation>,</alarmSpecification>
```